# Re-entrancy in Java saves us from a deadlock situation in this code sample.. How, why?

Tags: java, multithreading, reentrancy

I'm new to Java and OOP. I'm reading concurrency in java and in chapter 2, it talks about re-entrancy. I don't quite understand how a deadlock situation would occur. Can some one break this situation down for me to understand the details line by line?

Thank you in advance.

> If intrinsic locks were not reentrant, the call to super.doSomething
>   would never be able to acquire the lock because it would be 
>   considered  already  held, and the  thread would  permanently  stall 
>   waiting  for a  lock  it can never  acquire.

```
public class Widget {
    public synchronized void doSomething() {
      ...
    }
}
public class LoggingWidget extends Widget {
   public synchronized void doSomething() {
      System.out.println(toString() + ": calling doSomething");
      super.doSomething();
   }
}
```

> and the  thread would  permanently  stall  waiting  for a  lock  it
>   can never  acquire.

How, why, which thread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How, why, which thread?

The thread that deadlocks is the thread that attempts to acquire the lock; i.e. this one.

---

How:

1. Obtain reference to a `LoggingWidget` instance
2. Call `doSomething()` on the instance
3. The call to `LoggingWidget.doSomething()` acquires the lock on the instance, since the method is `synchronized`.
4. The called method then calls `super.doSomething()`.
5. The call to `Widget.doSomething()` tries to acquire the lock on the instance (again!), since the supertype method is also `synchronized`.

At step #5. the current thread attempts to acquire a primitive lock on an instance that it has already locked.  If primitive locks were not reentrant, then that would deadlock ...

- "some thread" already holds the lock on the object, so we have to wait for that thread to release the lock,
- that "some thread" is the current thread ... and we are not going to release the lock until we return from the `LoggingWidget.doSomething()`
- but that can't happen until after we've completed the call to `Widget.doSomething()`
- and that can't happen until after we've acquired the lock
- ..... DEADLOCK!

But fortunately, there is no deadlock in reality.  The fact that primitive locks are reentrant means that step #5 doesn't need to *acquire* the lock (it already has it), and the whole waiting-for-myself-to-do-something-that-cannot-happen scenario simply does not arise.

---

Why:  By the inescapable power of [Murphy's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law). *"If anything can go wrong, it will."* :-)

Which thread:  According to [Finagle's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finagle%27s_law), it will be the one that causes the most damage. :-)

<sup>These so-called "laws" have not been demonstrated scientifically.  But that doesn't mean you should ignore what they are intended to teach.</sup>

Comment: Thank you Stephen. Awesomely explained!

Answer (score 2):

I think you got confused by the author's use of the word re-entrancy. By "locks are re-entrant" he meant that if your thread holds a lock already, Java allows entering a `synchronized` method from inside another `synchronized` method, or re-entering the same `synchronized` method recursively.

This is different from a more common meaning of re-entrancy as the ability of a piece of code to be re-entered, concurrently or on the same thread when the status is preserved.

Without re-entrancy in the author's meaning the `synchronized` of the `super.doSomething()` would block on trying to acquire the lock held by `this.doSomething()`, because they block on the same object (namely, on `this`).

Comment: I edited my question. At the end, I added a portion that I don't understand. I'm trying to understand the workflow of how the method would be called and the execution that would take place from a threading perspective and what would happen if reentrancy was not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You have two methods that lock on the same object - an instance of `LoggingWidget` - that would be run by the same thread.

1. An instance of `LoggingWidget` is created
2. The `doSomething` method defined in the `LoggingWidget` class is called against that instance
3. A lock on the instance of `LoggingWidget` is obtained
4. The `println` statement is executed
5. The `doSomething` method of the `LoggingWidget` class calls the `doSomething` method defined in the `Widget` class
6. A lock on the same instance of `LoggingWidget` is needed to proceed, but it's already held by the thread executing the first method

If locks were not re-entrant, a deadlock would occur at step 6 since the lock on the instance is already held. But since built-in `Object` locks in Java are re-entrant, step 6 continues as normal since the lock that is needed is already held by the executing thread.