# Is this a synchronized deadlock situation in android java?

Tags: java, android

Is instantiating an instance of SynchroClass as defined below and calling `sCMethod` going to cause a deadlock when the second `sCMethod` tries to get a lock on `lockObject`?

SO suggests I might mean something like [Re-entrancy in Java saves us from a deadlock situation in this code sample.. How, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21518938/832705), which seems to suggest that it is not a deadlock as the same object already has the lock ownership, but that talks about `synchronized` methods, so is at least a little different.

```
class SynchroClass {
    static Object lockObject = new Object();
    private boolean otherCondition = true;

    public boolean sCMethod(boolean condition) {
        synchronized(lockObject) {
            if(condition) {
                // some code
            } else if(otherCondition) {
                // some code
                sCMethod(false);
                // some code 
            } else {
                // some code
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't deadlock because the thread already has the lock. It works for the same reason that recursion works on a synchronized method.

Comment: @flkes, that seems right, I guess I was figuring the synchronized code block was the thing that had the lock more than the containing instance object

Comment: It isn't deadlock because there is only one thing to lock. Deadlock arises when there are two or more locks acquired in different orders.